# How to use the drag formula method in openxml

Tags: c#, .net-core, openxml, openxml-sdk

I want to use the excel drag formula through code.
The way in Excel we drag the formula to the cells below so that the formula falls on all the cells and it gets calculated. I am trying to implement something similar. I am using Document.OpenXML. How can I implement it? Snippets will be really helpful

Comment: It's not clear what you mean. You can't use a mouse to drag things in code, obviously.  So do you mean you simply want to copy cells programmatically as you would with a formula drag?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I would want to copy cells programmatically as it works in formula drag

Comment: There's no "formula drag". Formulas use ranges, eg "A1:F3" or "A:F". Excel helps you specify ranges through a window. That window also allows you to drag to specify ranges. What matters is the *range*, not the tool used to calculate it